# JUnit4 test case with coroutines

Tags: kotlin, mockito, kotlin-coroutines, junit4

I am writing viewModel junit test using mockito.

My `viewModel` class is as follows.

```
@HiltViewModel
class DeviceHolderListViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: DeviceHolderListRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    private val _resultFlow = MutableStateFlow<Resource<DeviceHolder>?>(null)
    val resultFlow: StateFlow<Resource<DeviceHolder>?> = _resultFlow

    init {
        getList()
    }

    fun getList() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _resultFlow.update { Resource.Loading }
            val result = repository.getList()
            _resultFlow.update { result }
        }
    }
}
```

My related test case as follows:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class DeviceHolderListViewModelTest {

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    @get:Rule
    val mainDispatcherRule = MainDispatcherRule()

    @Mock
    private lateinit var repository: DeviceHolderListRepository

    private lateinit var viewModel: DeviceHolderListViewModel

    private val customerList = listOf(
        Customer(
            firstName = "John",
            gender = "Male",
            id = 1,
            imageUrl = "https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/473/200/300.jpg?hmac=WYG6etF60iOJeGoFVY1hVDMakbBRS32ZDGNkVZhF6-8",
            lastName = "Doe",
            phoneNumber = "123-456-7890",
            stickers = listOf("Sticker 1", "Sticker 2")
        ),
        Customer(
            firstName = "Jane",
            gender = "Female",
            id = 2,
            imageUrl = "https://example.com/jane.jpg",
            lastName = "Smith",
            phoneNumber = "9876543210",
            stickers = listOf("Sticker 3", "Sticker 4")
        )
    )

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
        viewModel = DeviceHolderListViewModel(repository)
    }


    @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
    @Test
    fun `should update resultFlow with the expected result` () = runTest {
        val testDeviceHolder = DeviceHolder(customerList)

        // Set up the mock behavior for the repository
        `when`(repository.getList()).thenReturn(Resource.Success(testDeviceHolder))

        //Observe the resultFlow value
        viewModel.getList()

        val resultFlowValue = viewModel.resultFlow.value

        assertEquals(resultFlowValue, testDeviceHolder)

    }
}
```

I am getting `null` value in `resultFlowValue` variable. What I am doing incorrect?